# Maths: Algorithm to work out how much stock can be moved

Tags: math

This might seem a trivial maths question, but I am hoping you can help.

Here is the scenario.

> A warehouse has a maximum `capacity` of 50 crates
>
> It has a current `stock` of 10 crates
>
> I want to move `X`` crates, where X can be any number.
>
> E.G: A truck comes along and wants to deliver X crates (lets say 1000 crates).
>
> I want to split the number to keep any overflow of crates on the truck and move `capacity` minus `stock` crates and the rest stays on the truck.

I can do a formula like this:

`50 = X + Y`

Where X is the crates I want to move in and Y is the current stock

But this doesn't work if your numbers start getting bigger.

ie;

`1110 = 1000 + 10` breaks the above formula

Is there an algorithm or mathematical solution to allow me to move X crates but always ensure the rules of capacity are stuck to, and keep the overflow of crates on the delivery truck?

Many thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths

Comment: It is a simple addition/subtraction. What does not work? Show your code please.

Comment: `X = 50 - Y ∀ Y <= 50`. Your problem with your second formula is that it's wrong... It should be `50 = 1000 + 10`, which is also wrong because you're trying to insert too many crates into the warehouse. You need to limit the number of crates you deliver.

Comment: Yes, I need to limit the crates.  I will try some basic if/else statements too as I think this would help too

Comment: I was trying to make it work regardless of the number of crates.  So if I happen to move 1000 crates in, it would know to subtract from this and keep the rest on the truck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move min(truck, capacity - warehouse) crates into the warehouse.

Here truck is the number of crates on the truck, warehouse is the number of crates in the warehouse, and capacity is the maximum number of crates the warehouse can hold.